# set UIImageView.image in prepareForSegue

Tags: objective-c

I want to segue to a photoViewController that has an UIImageView. 
In flickrTVC, I say:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showPhoto"])
    {
        photoViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
        UIImage *photo = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"images/en.jpeg"];
        [vc setDisplayedPhoto:photo];
    }
}
```

and the setDisplayedPhoto method's implementation is:

```
-(void)setDisplayedPhoto:(UIImage *)image
{
    [_imageView setImage:image]; //@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
}
```

But when I do segue, the UIImageView is white... Why could this be?

Comment: Your image path is probably wrong. Test if `photo == nil`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your destination view controller hasn't loaded its view hierarchy by the time your source view controller receives the `prepareForSegue:sender:` message.  So your destination VC's `_imageView` variable is `nil`.

The recommended approach is to store the image (or, probably even better, the image file name) as a property of the destination VC, and then set the image view's image in the destination VC's `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear:` method.

Answer (score 0):

Call [vc view] before setting the o of the view