# Using prepareforsegue to pass an image from a button to an image view

Tags: iphone, xcode

I need your help please.
I have two different view controllers:
1. with a button
2. with an image view.

I'm trying to pass the button's image to the image view at the second view controller.
The prepareforsegue is being called but the image does not pass.
I attached my code:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"pushGuessLogo"])
    {
         GeneralGuess *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
          [self setLogoImageView:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:self.logoImageSelected.imageView.image]];

        [vc setImageGuessView:self.logoImageView]; 
    }

}
```

ImageGuessView is the outlet of the image view at view controller number 2.

Thank you

Comment: What happens if you insert `UIImageView *test = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:self.logoImageSelected.imageView.image];  NSLog(@"Test: %@", test);` in there to see what you're attempting to pass?

Comment: possible duplicate of [set UIImageView.image in prepareForSegue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11515643/set-uiimageview-image-in-prepareforsegue)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Someone answered this the other day but I'm too lazy to find the link. *(wouldn't it be great if SO also had a Knowledge Base which questions get promoted to, rather than endless questions that do not come up in a search)*.

The gist is that the viewController's view hierarchy is not yet set up at the point of `prepareForSegue`, so your `ImageGuessView` is nil at that point. What you can do is define a `UIImage` property on your `GeneralGuess` class and set that. Then in `viewWillAppear` load that image into your `ImageGuessView`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11515643/set-uiimageview-image-in-prepareforsegue/11515796#11515796

Answer (score 0):

The destination is not yet loaded when `prepareForSegue` is called so the image view is `nil` and thus nothing happens what you try to set the image.

Instead you should pass the image and store it in a property on the destination view controller and later set it in the image view in the destination view controllers `viewDidLoad`